# Get all records of a specific type mapping in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How do I get all records from Elastic search that belong to a given type within an index.

I use the below to get all records that belong to storedb index :

```
curl -XGET 'http://<ip>:9200/storedb/_search?pretty=true&q=*.*'
```

But I can't seem to find the ElasticSearch documentation that specifies this operation per type.

Comment: Search specific type documented at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

Comment: Can you be more specific towards what you need and what you have tried. Give examples.